# mysql : non-latin characters are not ordered by desc

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SELECT stc_student.id, group_concat(stc_score.teacher_name) as 评分老师, 
       student_name, ifnull(cast(avg(score) as DECIMAL(18,0)),'') as 平均成绩, 
       student_class,student_worklinks,created_at FROM stc_score 
       RIGHT JOIN stc_student ON ( stc_student.id=stc_score.id) 
       GROUP BY stc_student.id ORDER BY 平均成绩 DESC;
```

displays:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+
| id        | 评分老师                                  | student_name | 平均成绩     | student_class | student_worklinks     | created_at |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+
| 100160728 | 汤佳,周耀鹏,徐力,李力亚,evilhui           | 王晖         | 64           | 移动1603      | /100160728/index.html | 1493201986 |
| 100160110 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 5            | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160111 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 5            | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160112 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 5            | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160113 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 5            | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160115 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 5            | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160705 | evilhui                                   | 段家峰       | 5            | 移动1601      | /100160705            | 1495812165 |
| 100160713 | evilhui                                   | 徐昶         | 5            | 移动1603      | 健康路记录i           | 1495812877 |
| 343544442 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 5            | 移动1603      | asdas                 | 1495813142 |
| 425688411 | evilhui                                   | 王晖         | 5            | 移动1603      | esfer                 | 1495815475 |
| 100160729 | 周耀鹏,evilhui                            | 晓杰         | 43           | 移动1603      | /100160728/index.html | 1493201986 |
| 100160120 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 33           | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160114 | evilhui                                   | 刘杰         | 2            | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160733 | evilhui                                   | 王晖         | 10           | 移动1603      | 暂无                  | 1495611800 |
| 111111111 | evilhui                                   | 吕世惠       | 10           | 移动1601      | 晋中地区昔阳县        | 1495811266 |
| 123567777 | evilhui                                   | asd          | 10           | 移动1603      | 123213                | 1495813419 |
| 434655555 | evilhui                                   | 阿斯顿       | 10           | 移动1603      | asa                   | 1495813337 |
| 776766666 | evilhui                                   | 阿斯顿       | 10           | 移动1603      | 还行                  | 1495815915 |
| 987654321 | evilhui                                   | 最后测试     | 10           | 移动1602      | 欧美style             | 1495814028 |
| 100001111 | NULL                                      | 王晖         |              | 移动1603      | NULL                  | 1495987456 |
| 100001112 | NULL                                      | 王晖         |              | 移动1603      | NULL                  | 1495988224 |
| 100160116 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160117 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160118 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160119 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160121 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160122 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160123 | NULL                                      | 刘杰         |              | 移动1603      | 111                   | 1495566211 |
| 100160623 | NULL                                      | 郭峰斌       |              | 移动1601      | /100160623/index.html | 1495565545 |
| 100160731 | NULL                                      | 吕倩         |              | 移动1603      | /100160728/index.html | 1493201986 |
| 100160922 | NULL                                      | 王超         |              | 移动1602      | /100160729/index.html | 1493201986 |
| 100160923 | NULL                                      | 王超         |              | 移动1603      | /100160729/index.html | 1493201986 |
| 100200300 | NULL                                      | 段家风       |              | 移动1603      |                       | 1495999675 |
| 123134444 | NULL                                      | 王晖         |              | 移动1603      | NULL                  | 1495566211 |
| 130120110 | NULL                                      | 吕林         |              | 移动1603      | NULL                  | 1495999675 |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+
```

平均成绩`column is not sorted

Answer (score 0):

check the actual MySQL server `my.cnf` file. The following would set the whole chain to UTF-8:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

Comment: Stop using UTF-8 in MySQL, and [use **`UTF8mb4`** instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @Martin Yes! Totally right, my bad there is a need to update... thank you so so much